# Column header filter works when logged in, but not on public site

Tags: document-library, filter, public-website

I've created a public site. It includes a document library (of conference white papers). I've added lookup columns from custom lists for the conferences the paper was presented at and the categories the paper applies to. I've created a custom view that includes those columns and put that view on a page.

When I'm logged into Office 365 and I bring up the page, I can filter on those columns using the column header dropdown. But when I publish the page to my public site, the filters don't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you see any Javascript error in browser while hitting the Public site? also are you using the Http or Https on public site?

Comment: No, no errors of any type. HTTP. The site has actually been live for months, and now I'm trying to solve this particular problem. The relevant page is http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/publications/conferencepapers.